# Define module with dependencies for AMD (requirejs) and Common.js (Node.js) and global scope

Tags: node.js, requirejs, global, amd, commonjs

I'm trying to create a function that accessible with AMD, Common.js, and in the Global Scope. My one caveat is that it has dependancies. Require.js and global scope seem to be working fine but I can't get the dependencies to load in Node.js.

```
(function(global, factory) {
  // Node.js
  if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    moment = require('moment');
    return module.exports = factory();

  }
  // require.js
  else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    return define(['moment'], function(moment) {
      global.moment = moment;
      return factory();
    });
  }
  // global
  else {
    return global.formatDate = factory();
  }
})(this, function() {

  var formatDate = function(date, format) {
    if (typeof moment !== 'function' && !moment) {
      console.error('moment is required to format date')
      return date;
    }
   return moment(date).format(format);
  };

  return formatDate;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exposing dependencies as globals, pass them as arguments to your factory.

For example:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([ 'module', 'moment' ], function (module, moment) {
            module.exports = factory(moment);
        });
    } else if (typeof module === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('moment'));
    } else {
        root.formatDate = factory(root.moment);
    }
}(this, function (moment) {

}));
```

Check out the Universal Module Definition (UMD) recipes at https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Comment: https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/returnExports.js looks like a good solution. I'll give a try—thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with if anyone is interested:

```
(function(root, factory) {

  // AMD (require.js)
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    return define(['moment'], factory);

  // CommonJS (Node.js)
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    return module.exports = factory(require('moment'));

  // Browser Globals
  } else {
    return root.formatDate = factory(root.moment);
  }

})(this, function(moment) {

  var formatDate = function(date, format) {
    return date.format(format);
  };

  return formatDate;
});
```

I referenced Universal Module Definition [returnExports](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/returnExports.js) mentioned by @Ates Goral